# Loading dataframe from dynamodb - aws glue pyspark

Tags: pyspark, etl, aws-glue

I'm trying to read the records from dynamodb table. I have tried to use the dynamic frame. Since I have 8 million records in my table it was taking too long time to filter. Anyway I don't need to load 8 million records to dataframe.Instead of applying filter in dynamic frame, I want to know is any option is available to load dataframe by passing query. So few records only loaded to dataframe and it will work faster.

Comment: I am in the same situation. How did you achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can load dataframe by passing a query in `spark.sql()` but before that, you will have to run the `AWS Glue crawler` on the `Dynamo DB` table so that you can get a  table corresponding to that `Dynamo DB` table in AWS `Glue catalog` and then you can use this table generated in `Glue Catalog` to read data using Spark dataframe directly.